# Unsupported SubQuery Expression : Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

In `Hive` the following query fails :

```
  Select a,b,c from t1 where a in (0,100) AND b in (select b from t2
  where d>2 GROUP BY 1 ) LIMIT 1;
```

Schema :

```
t1(a,b,c)
t2(b,d,e)
```

Error log :

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'b': Correlating expression cannot
>   contain unqualified column references.

What is correlating expression? what are unqualified column references ? and can you generalize the error here ..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find someone having the same problem [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/idea/2082/bulk-updates-in-hive.html) and the corresponding [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9734).

Based on those answers, I would advise you to try :

```
Select a,b,c from t1 where a in (0,100) AND t1.b in (select b from t2
  where d>2 GROUP BY 1 ) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: yeah that works .. but I couldn't find the exact meaning of 'correlating expression'

Comment: it seems to be a broad term that Hive is using here to refer to the `<something> in (select...)` syntax

Answer (score 8):

It is because you have `b` in both queries, the main one and the inner within the `in` statement. To fix it you have to explicitly tell hive to which `b` you're referring to. That's why changing it to `t1.b` solves it.