# SQL Query, Multiple Selections

Tags: sql, hive

Assume the data is of the format

```
       ID                  Category     
       14424342             241
       14424342             17
       14234154             243
          .                  .
          .                  .
```

I want to create a table that has only the Ids and categories where Cat = 241

for the query I have

```
        SELECT ID & Category FROM Table1 WHERE Category = 241
```

That returns

```
                     ID                Category 
                 14424342             241
```

But I also want the query to show every category corresponding to that ID.

Something that would return

```
                   ID                   Category
                14424342                 241
                14424342                 17
                14424342                 41
                15238991                 241
                15238991                 91
                    .                     .
```

Almost as if it were an if statement, if Cat = 241 return ID and Show each category associated with the ID

Comment: Can you revise your question? Your example does not make much sense.

Comment: `Assume the data is of the format

       ID                  Category     

       14424342             241
       14424342             17
       14234154             243
          .                  .
          .                  .   
          .                  . 

I want to create a table that has only the Ids and categories where Cat = 241` I don't get it. Create table may be? Or select something? If so, why would you want to return ID corrosponding to category 17 as for example.?

Comment: When I filter by category of 241 this returns all the IDs associated with this number, I am more interested in the connection between category 241 and other categories. I need help creating a statement that filters by category 241 and also shows every other category the filtered ID has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery of some sorts.

```
select ID, Category
from Table1
where ID in (select ID from Table1 where Category = 241)
```

Comment: when compiling this in Hive, I receive the error "unsupported subquery expression: correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references".

Do you know any work arounds?

Comment: I am not familiar with hive, but according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206818/unsupported-subquery-expression-correlating-expression-cannot-contain-unqualif), try `select ID, Category from Table1 where Table1.ID in (select ...`

Comment: Just found the proper hive syntax, my results return
                 0
                 1
                 2, etc as the id instead of the actual id.