# How to use result of LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE in a subquery?

Tags: hive

I am trying to make a query like this:

`select * from tbl
LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(column) temp_tbl as the_col
WHERE (the_col IN (select column from tbl2))`

and it gives this error:

> Unsupported SubQuery Expression: Correlating expression cannot contain
>   unqualified column references

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37208400/147530) answer and changed the query to:

`select * from tbl
LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(column) temp_tbl as the_col
WHERE (tbl.the_col IN (select column from tbl2))`

and now I get this error:

> FAILED: SemanticException Line XX:XX Invalid column reference
>   'the_col' in definition of SubQuery sq_1

What's going on here and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT * FROM tbl 
         LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(column) temp_tbl as the_col ) a
WHERE a.the_col IN (select column from tbl2);
```