# Error with Hive SubQuery - Unsupported SubQuery Expression

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, impala

```
create table db.temp
location '/user/temp' as
SELECT t1.mobile_no
FROM db.temp t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM db.temp t2
                   WHERE t1.mobile_no = t2.mobile_no
                     AND t1.cell != t2.cell
                     AND t2.access_time BETWEEN t1.access_time
                                            AND t1.access_time_5);
```

I need to get all the users who used the same cell for 5 hours of the time interval(`access_time_5`) from `access time`. This code perfectly fine with impala. But not works in Hive.

Gives an error

> "Error while compiling statement: FAILED:
> SemanticException [Error 10249]: line 23:25 Unsupported SubQuery
> Expression"

I looked at a similar question related to this error. Can't figure out the solution. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported SubQuery Expression : Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206818/unsupported-subquery-expression-correlating-expression-cannot-contain-unqualif)

Comment: Hi @mck. I tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37208400/10350548). But it not worked!

Comment: correlated BETWEEN is not supported in Hive.

Comment: Hi @leftjoin! Any solution for getting rid of this issue?

Comment: Could you post some data example?

Comment: It's hard to provide a sample dataset. because I'm working on a safe harbor environment. If I brief about the nature of the dataset, It's a call record dataset. when a user connected to our network, we are recording the mobile number and the time that the user logged in plus a user-assigned cell id(and more.). what I need to do is extract the users who used the same cell for a five-hour time interval. I supposed to use min access time as a user's first logged time.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated BETWEEN is not supported in Hive as well as non-equi joins. Try to rewrite using LEFT JOIN, count rows with your condition and filter:

```
select mobile_no from
(
SELECT t1.mobile_no, 
       sum(case when t1.cell != t2.cell
                 and t2.access_time between t1.access_time and t1.access_time_5
               then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt_exclude
  FROM db.temp t1
       LEFT JOIN db.temp t2 on t1.mobile_no = t2.mobile_no
 GROUP BY t1.mobile_no
)s
where cnt_exclude=0
```

The problem with such solution is that LEFT JOIN may produce huge duplication and it will affect performance, though it may work if the data is not too big.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that window functions would be better for both databases.  Let me assume that `access_time` is a Unix time (i.e. measured in seconds).  You can easily convert the value to such a time:

```
SELECT t1.mobile_no
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MIN(t1.cell) OVER (PARTITION BY mobile_no
                                ORDER BY access_time
                                RANGE BETWEEN 17999 preceding AND CURRENT ROW
                               ) as min_cell,
             MAX(t1.cell) OVER (PARTITION BY mobile_no
                                ORDER BY access_time
                                RANGE BETWEEN 17999 preceding AND CURRENT ROW
                               ) as max_cell
      FROM db.temp t1
     ) t1
WHERE min_cell = max_cell;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon.Thanks for the answer. But It gives me an error **Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies**. Any suggetion to solve this?

Comment: @S.Abeyrathne . . . I do not really see how this query could produce that error.  I assume all the referenced columns are in `db.temp`.